# Python datetime to int

Tags: python

I'm returning a datetime object that I wish to convert to int. For example:

```
print var, type(var)
5 day, 0:00:00 <type 'datetime.timedelta'>
```

How to return `5` as int?

Comment: `var.days`? what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: note that this is a timedelta object. It doesn't make any sense to convert a datetime object to an int.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example you should do `var.days`